# RCurl on Synology NAS cannot find curl-config

Tags: curl, rcurl, synology

I'm trying to install a library in R on my Synology NAS. One of the requirements is `RCurl` library which fails to install with the following error:

```
install.packages("RCurl")                                                       
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’                         
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)                                                       
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RCurl_1.98-1.2.tar.gz'      
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 699583 bytes (683 KB)                  
==================================================                              
downloaded 683 KB                                                               

* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...                                       
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked                   
checking for curl-config... no                                                  
Cannot find curl-config                                                         
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’                                 
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RCurl’                                

The downloaded source packages are in                                           
        ‘/tmp/RtmpHtl2dQ/downloaded_packages’                                   
Warning message:                                                                
In install.packages("RCurl") :                                                  
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

It's the first time I try R on my NAS. This is what I managed to do until now:

- install r-base in Docker,
- get connected with my NAS through SSH with admin rights,
- check version of curl:

```
root@MyNAS:/# curl --version
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.54.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2r zlib/1.2.8 c-ares/1.12.0 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.24.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS Debug TrackMemory IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

Does anyone of you know how should I make it work?

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://github.com/sagemath/cloud/issues/114)? I just searched for your error, but can't test it here. Feel free to write and accept your own answer here if it works.

Comment: Thanks, @Useless. Of course I did the research before : ) I'm not a Linux expert and the Linux on my NAS seems to be some light version and doesn't have commands like `locate` or `apt-get`. `uname -a` writes
Linux MyNAS 3.10.105 #24922 SMP Wed Jul 3 16:34:56 CST 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_braswell_916+ if it helps.